# How to choose between bagof, setof and findall in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

How does one choose between bagof, setof and findall? Are there any important differences? Which is most commonly used and which is the safest? Thanks for your comments/answers.

I checked the [SWI-Prolog manual page on `findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) and found them to be very similar.

Comment: The link you gave explains `findall/3` versus `bagof/3`. `setof/3` is like `bagof/3` except it removes redundant solutions (elements in the result list are unique) and it sorts the results in ascending order.

Comment: Short answer: depends what you want to achieve. You might get more _useful_ answers if you describe a concrete use case and compare the three (`bagof/3`, `setof/3`, and `findall/3`) in the context of your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a great question!

I am not attempting to give an exhaustive answer, but I would like to suggest a few lines of thought that can help you to understand these predicates better:

- Think about which of these predicates are more **fundamental** in the sense of *what can be expressed in terms of what*. For example, can you express `findall/3` in terms of `setof/3`? And what about the other way around? This helps to see what you need to provide *at least* to implement all these predicates.
- Think about which **declarative properties** are preserved by these predicates. For example, does the order in which the solutions are found influence the results? For which of these predicates precisely? Can any of these predicates **fail**? In which cases precisely?
- Think about the **space and time complexity** of each of these predicates. Which of these predicates, if any, can be implemented and used more efficiently than others? And at what cost and tradeoffs?

In addition, I recommend you read Richard O'Keefe's book **The Craft of Prolog** for valuable information about these predicates.

Answer (score 5):

an important difference I found between `findall/3` and `bagof/3`, is that the latter doesn't make copies of the terms it accumulates. This can be crucial, for instance, if your list collects *attributed variables*, like when modelling a problem with `library(clpfd)`.