# Generating 3 random numbers in Prolog: forall, foreach, findall, bagof, maplist

Tags: prolog, iteration

I want to generate 3 random numbers using what could be called "iteration & collection" predicates.

I'm collecting comments on any of the attempts below.

Writing a predicate inline is confusing and error-prone (or maybe even impossible with the `is` in there?), so we define:

```
side_effect_and_unify(X) :- 
   format("Called with ~w\n",X),
   X is random(100),
   format("Returning with ~w\n",X).
```

## Using  [`forall/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=forall2)

We read:

> The predicate `forall/2` (`forall(:Cond,:Action)`) is implemented as `\+ ( Cond, \+ Action)`, i.e., There is no instantiation of *Cond* for which *Action* is false..

This should "shield off" any variable instantiations whatsover. Not surprisingly:

```
?- length(L,3),forall(member(X,L),side_effect_and_unify(X)).
Called with _32964
Returning with 94
Called with _32964
Returning with 36
Called with _32964
Returning with 93
L = [_33490, _33496, _33502].
```

100% sure it's not possible to get those random numbers into `L`.

## Using [`foreach/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)

We read:

> Unlike `forall/2`, which runs a failure-driven loop that proves *Goal* for each solution of *Generator*, `foreach/2` creates a conjunction. Each member of the conjunction is a copy of *Goal*, where the variables it shares with *Generator* are filled with the values from the corresponding solution.

```
?- length(L,3),foreach(member(X,L),side_effect_and_unify(X)).
Called with _29916
Returning with 33
Called with _29916
Returning with 3
Called with _29916
Returning with 97
L = [_30434, _30440, _30446].
```

No joy, but is it possible?

The description makes me think this is what runs:

```
?- L=[L1,L2,L3],side_effect_and_unify(L1),side_effect_and_unify(L2),side_effect_and_unify(L3).
Called with _31202
Returning with 88
Called with _31208
Returning with 81
Called with _31214
Returning with 5
L = [88, 81, 5],
L1 = 88,
L2 = 81,
L3 = 5.
```

but apparently not.

## Using [`findall/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)

```
?- length(L,3),findall(X,(member(X,L),side_effect_and_unify(X)),Out).
Called with _28410
Returning with 75
Called with _28410
Returning with 18
Called with _28410
Returning with 66
L = [_29046, _29052, _29058],
Out = [75, 18, 66].
```

Yes!

## Using [`bagof/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)

`bagof/3` is friendlier, but we need to tell it to "not bind var `L` in the goal". I'm not entirely certain about the meaning: Apparently it means `L` is a variable over the goal, so it can take on the value defined for the `L` *outside* the goal.

Although [here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) we read:

> This features shines when combined with `bagof/3` or `setof/3` where you normally have to specify the the variables in whose binding you are not interested using the `Var^Goal` construct (marking `Var` as existential quantified).

This would mean the opposite: `L` is a free variable inside the goal (but then the line below wouldn't work). What's the right way to think about this?

```
?- length(L,3),bagof(X,L^(member(X,L),side_effect_and_unify(X)),Out).
Called with _24336
Returning with 10
Called with _24336
Returning with 24
Called with _24336
Returning with 22
L = [_24912, _24918, _24924],
Out = [10, 24, 22].
```

Another speciality of `bagof/3` based on a remark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172507/how-to-choose-between-bagof-setof-and-findall-in-prolog):

> [it] doesn't copies terms it accumulates in list. This can be fundamental, for instance, when your list will collect attributed variables, like to ones you use when modelling a problem with library(clpfd).

## Using [`maplist/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2)

Ok, that's easy.

```
?- length(L,3),maplist(side_effect_and_unify,L).
Called with _26224
Returning with 23
Called with _26230
Returning with 63
Called with _26236
Returning with 70
L = [23, 63, 70].
```

Not only nicer, but IMHO, actually viably readable with yall. You actually *see* the metacall:

```
?- length(L,3),maplist([X]>>side_effect_and_unify(X),L).
Called with _27420
Returning with 34
Called with _27426
Returning with 41
Called with _27432
Returning with 25
L = [34, 41, 25].
```